# Top N Filter Shows N/A When Applied

Tags: filter, tableau-api

I have a weird problem in Tableau - I've set a Top 10 filter for Models by count but when I add any filters, the Top 10 worksheets just shows "N/A". The reason this is odd is because if I duplicate the worksheet and simply remove the Top 10 aspect filter, but keep all other filters active, it shows that there are over 30 models listed. So why is it showing "N/A" whenever I set it to Top 10? I tried using a parameter as well to use in the Top 10 calculation but that didn't solve anything (was worth a try just to eliminate all possibilities!). Any idea what the issue could be? It's such a weird issue.

I've tried building new worksheets from scratch without any universally applied filters as well - and I get the same issues.

I've looked this up online but haven't found an article about a similar issue.

Below are snapshots of the issues I'm having:
[With Top N Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEawX.png)
[Without Top N Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce1YK.png)

Comment: Hi, did my below answer assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your workbook I suspect you are having an issue with order of operations in Tableau. Table calculations such as Top 10 are applied **before** filters. So I think what is happening is none of the records within your filter are within the top 10 of the entire table. If the effect you are after is to calculate the top 10 for the subset defined by your filter specifications then you need to make the filters **context filters**. To do this right click on the filter and select add to context. This will make the filter turn grey. Do this for all filters where you want the top 10 to be calculated from.

Hope this makes sense. If it is not the effect you are after feel free to upload your workbook and I can take a look.

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/order_of_operations.html